# How to debug JavaCV cvCreatefileCapture on Ubuntu 13.03

Tags: javacv

I have some JavaCV code that works on windows and I'm trying to get it to work on Ubuntu.  All of the image processing is working fine, but I can't get any video to work.

When I call cvCreateFileCapture on Ubuntu it always returns null.  I can verify the file is present (java.io.File.exists returns true on the line before), so I assume this is a codec problem.

However, I have tried using video files with MPEG-2, H.264, AVI, and basic mjpeg encodings and get the same result for all of them.  The same code works fine on my windows machine.

My question is what are the next debugging steps to figure out my problem.  Randomly trying further codecs doesn't seem productive.  Is there some way to figure out which codecs are available and why they are not getting selected?

It is picking up the opencv libraries by having opencv-linux-x86_64.jar and ffmpeg-linux-x86_64.jar in the path.